# What exactly is a "corrupted workspace"?

Tags: eclipse

I've been working on an Android project in Eclipse Indigo for a year on a PC that has updates turned off and no new software installed (deliberately to avoid any instability in the java runtime or other installed software).

This morning Eclipse froze and when I killed it in Task Manage, rebooted the PC and restarted Eclipse it failed to launch, saying

> "Eclipse failed, Java was started but returned exit code=-805306369”

Googling this I discovered here . . .
http://spacetech.dk/eclipse-failed-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-805306369.html

. . . that this is due to a "corrupted workspace".   And that I should rename the workspace, create a new empty one, and import the old project into it.

**1.** What **exactly** is a "corrupted workspace"?   Is there a particular file that's missing or damaged or locked?  Can the "corruption" be debugged?   A chkdsk didn't show any problems with the disk.  I've never had this happen in Visual Studio with C# projects and I do more Windows development than Android.

**2.**  What's the process for importing the old project into the new workspace, and how do I do it without importing the corruption?    It's a big project with hundreds of files so I don't want to try to recreate it by hand.

Comment: a `workspace` is a set of configuration files defining the projects opened, runtimes, theme, preferences ... If any of those files gets messed up (for example, because it has been partially overwritten), the workspace cannot work anymore. It is unlikely to be salvaged. (and it does not have usually anything to do with problems on the disk itself.)

Comment: The important thing is that `workspace` and `project` are separated concepts, and you should be able to import a project in any workspace, even if it has been in a corrupted one.

Answer (score 0):

The workspace is a set of configuration files and your projects, though projects can also exist outside of the workspace. The are configuration files for most of the eclipse plugins you have installed, I suspect one of these is causing the problem.

The configuration is stored in a hidden folder in the workspace called .metadata, their is also a log file in this folder called .log. This log file might give you more of a clue as to what has broken.

You can delete (or move it somewhere else) the .metadata folder and eclipse will recreate it next time it's launched. You will then need to reimport your projects and configure eclipse again.

To reimport your projects, use the import wizard from the "File -> Import" menu item. Select the "General -> Existing projects into workspace" wizard. Now click the "Browse" button and find your projects. Select the projects you want to import and click "Finish". Your workspace should now contain your projects again.